# How to change arm version in arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc for cross compile

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I want to cross-compile in `eclipse` for board `armv7l`.
I got the `armv7l` via, `uname -i`.
I installed ARM cross compiler toolchain, using below commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get install emdebian-archive-keyring
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
$ sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
$ sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
$ sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

I think I have to give an option for my target board version.

First time I tried to put `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++` in `C/C++ Build->settings->GCC C++ Compiler` and `GCC C++ Linker`.(eclipse project properties)

Next I put `-march=armv7` in `Miscellaneous`

But it was not working. I checked the executable file with `readelf -A` 
and it shows this

```
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

What option I have to put for my target board ?

Comment: Define "not working" - you wanted ARMv7 code, you have an executable with ARMv7 code in it; within the stated boundaries of the question, there doesn't seem to be a problem there. Of course, a system is much more than a CPU architecture and an endianness, so there are plenty of other considerations and things that need matching up when cross-compiling, but we don't know what those are because you haven't said.

Comment: Unless very exceptional circumstances, you will want the arm-linux-gnueabihf (hardfloat) variants of the tools, not arm-linux-gnueabi.